# How to store and get color from a Bundle?

Tags: android, bundle, background-color

I'm working on portrait and landscape view of an Android Apps.
As the data are lost when we change orientations I thought to store the data in a bundle by overriding the method `onSavedInstanceState`and restoring the data from `onRestoreInstanceState`.
It is working fine but I want to store the background color of the app in the bundle since its a random color and I don't know what is the background color.

Can we do that or is there any other way around that can solve this problem?

Comment: "since its a random color and I don't know what is the background color" -- if it is random, you had to come up with the random color in Java code. Hence, you know what the color is.

Comment: I have the RGB values. So you are saying to pass those values and recreate the color??

Comment: Yes. Android is not going to automatically save the background color, because it does not think that it might be variable. So, hold onto to the color you set, save that in the `Bundle`, and re-apply it as needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass the color as an integer. Something similar to this example:

```
Random rnd = new Random(); 
int color = Color.argb(255, rnd.nextInt(256), rnd.nextInt(256), rnd.nextInt(256));   
view.setBackgroundColor(color);
```

Comment: I applied the same code but it didn't came up my mind to use that integer color... :P